# Can you temper store-bought chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, tempering

Is it possible and necessary to temper store-bought quality chocolate like Lindt?

Say, for example, you want to use it to make chocolate moulds - would it be possible to melt and temper the chocolate and have the same result as that of couverture chocolate?

Comment: Well they tempered it in the first place when they made the shape they sell it in.

Comment: Yes, but what happens when it is melted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can (Lindt dark chocolate bars work just fine).

Whether you can temper chocolate is simply a matter of whether there's enough cocoa butter (the fat that is actually crystallizing during the tempering process). You will want to have at least ~30% cocoa butter by mass if you want to temper the chocolate, but even 20% will work.

When you see a chocolate bar that says something like, "70% cocoa," that is the *sum* of the fat (cocoa butter) and non-fat parts (cocoa solids) of the cacao bean. That 70% might be divided between 30% fat and 40% cacao, for example, which is definitely sufficient for tempering.

If you want to know if a particular bar can be used for tempering, here's a quick test:

1. Read the label, and see if the primary fat is real cocoa butter
2. Make sure that the bar is at least 30% fat by mass

Small warning: different chocolates have different tempering curves. This is why dark, milk, and white chocolates generally have slightly different tempering curves. If you have a good, instant-read thermometer, it will help in the process of learning how to temper your chocolate of choice.

Comment: In the UK at least, a chocolate's percentage would measure the cocoa solids. E.g. Green & Blacks 70% dark chocolate says "Minimum Cocoa Solids 70%" on the packaging.

Comment: Careful, if you search for that product online, you will find that the packaging says one of three things: "70% cocoa," "70% cocoa content," or "70% cacao content." Again, those numbers represents the *sum* of [cocoa butter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_butter), plus [cocoa solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_solids) in the chocolate.

Comment: Are you suggesting that where the packaging that says "70% cocoa solids" it is incorrect? That seems very unlikely. Every other brand of dark chocolate I have checked says "Cocoa solids X%". Either your assertion is wrong or "cocoa solids" in this content means "cocoa mass" which would be misleading. Can you offer a source to back up your claim?

Answer (score 1):

Store-bought chocolate is sold tempered. You don't have to re-temper it.

In a comment, you also ask

> but what happens when it is melted?

If you do your chocolate work properly, it won't distemper. That means that you either work with the pure chocolate without going out of the proper temperature range, or you make something with the chocolate (e.g. a ganache) and precisely follow a good method (should be explained in your recipe or textbook). So there is nothing special you have to do.

If you worked with your chocolate in such a way that you distempered it, but without ruining it completely (it has not seized or similar), you can indeed temper it again.